# Why does the order of controls in document outline of visual studio 2010 not match what the designer view shows?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I'm new to Visual Studio; using 2010. I have inherited a project that has a lot of controls in one Form. At the top level in the Form are a TabControl, a TableLayoutPanel, a GroupBox, and a Button. They appear on the screen (top to bottom) in the order TabControl, GroupBox, TableLayoutPanel, Button. In the Document Outline they are shown in a different order: TableLayoutPanel first (topmost), Button, GroupBox, TabControl.

If I drag the TabControl to the top in the Document Outline, it goes to the bottom of the GUI as shown in the designer view.

Can anyone give me a foothold to getting started in understanding how this works? Specifically what is the meaning of the order in which the controls appear in the Document Outline?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. You've been 2 years on SO. Please, read How to ask a good question - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Could you remove at least newbie disclaimer and thanks?

Comment: I did not say I am a newbie on SO. I said I am a newbie to Visual Studio. I have read the how-to-ask several times, from the first few days that I was on SO until recently. I am trying to ask as specific a question as I know how. I don't know how to frame the question any better. Would something more specific like "Why do controls move on the GUI in ways that do not correspond to their position in the document outline?" Of can you give me a suggestion for a better question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Document Outline window displays controls by their z-order.  Overlap some controls and you'll see that those closest to the front are displayed closest to the top of the Document Outline window.

If two controls are docked to the same edge of their parent, the position of each control relative to that edge is determined by z-order.  Those controls with the lowest z-index will be furthest from the edge.

In short, the order in the Document Window has absolutely no relationship to the `Location` properties of the controls.  It depends on z-order only.

Comment: The Z order is determined by the order of the children in the list of children (a property of the parent Control). In designer the order you add children to the parent (drag/drop) becomes their order in parent (so their Z order). Some odd interaction remains in my GUI between Z order and Location x,y) that eludes me. Solution: rebuild the GUI using a more systematic approach to what is being used to contain the 'basic' Control objects. In general this means buttons, label, text will be placed in suitable container controls and the containers will be nested in a systematic way.