# Why am I unable to change panel order in visual studio document outline?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm new to C# and I'm currently trying to make a small program. The coding is going great, but I'm stuck with a problem regarding panels, picture boxes and what not.

I want to change the order of the panels that's in the form using the document outline, but no such luck. The only way for me to move things infront of other objects is by using the move to front or move to back function, which seems tedious. When I try to move objects in the document outline, I only get the red stop sign telling me the option is not availabe.

Any thoughts?

Here's a view of the outline:
[image]

Comment: show the scenario. are those panels in different containers, which are in turn in different control hierarchies? does setting the zorder property change the outline? related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26416153/1132334

Comment: Hello!
I added a picture of the outline, I'll check out the link you provided as well. 

but to give some more info, I can't change any position what so ever. I'm blocked from controling any positioning

Comment: confirmed in a minimal example project. hierarchy control buttons are always disabled. successfully building does not help. reopening does not help. related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65901758/1132334

Comment: That's the exact same issue. I'm unable to find any sort of info on how to fix it. Thought that this place if any would have some Ideas

Comment: Saw this thread, seems that the microsoft teams knows about it at least.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1234842/winform-net-core-controls-document-outline-bug.html

Comment: give it time. someone's writing up an answer as we speak, probably. the document outline sure is a rather obscure feature, many of my fellow developers never heard of it until I showed them the "other windows" menu. but it is useful and it would be a pity if this is a bug not fixed any time soon. I just got a notification to update VS 2019 maybe the fix is in today's update :)

Comment: You should specify the Visual Studio Version and what Framework version you're using. -- If you're building a .Net Core 3.1 app, I suggest you move to .Net 5 or .Net Framework.

Comment: could reproduce in: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.8.3, Windows Forms, Framework 4.8.04084

Comment: Note that you can bind shortcuts to `BringToFront` and `SendToBack`, in `Tools->Customize->Commands->Keyboard`: then `Format.BringToFront` and `Format.SendToBack`. You can use the shortcuts when you select a Control in the Document Outline pane.